# How to use divs to get html table?

Tags: html, css-tables

I know it is probably dumb to create `table`s with `div`s when I can actually use tables easily.
But, this is necessary for now, later on there will possibly be some CSS changes added to a `div`.

For now I want the layout to look like the following:

[image: table layout]

1. This is like 3 by 3 table with some padding in between
2. I need to have the whole thing absolutely centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your browser support. This will work in modern browsers:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MGcYw/3/)

**Html:**

```
<div class="DivTable">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Cell{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.Cell:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}

.Row{
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.Row:first-child{
    margin-top:0px;
}

.DivTable{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use it [960 Grid](http://960.gs/), it is having the same with variable div width and margin between them

Comment: see the link-http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/mastering-the-960-grid-system/